# what is delete command for sharepoint menuitemtemplate

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, modal-dialog, delete

```
MenuTemplate menuTemplate = new MenuTemplate();

menuItem = new MenuItemTemplate("Delete document", "/_layouts/images/delete.gif");
            menuItem.ClientOnClickScript = ""; // What should I put there
            menuTemplate.Controls.Add(menuItem);
```

On line, menuItem.ClientOnClickScript, what should I put there, so that I can delete document?

Answer (score 1):

You need to call a Javascript (or SharePoint JS-ECMA) function passing "this" as a parameter (plus any other parameters you see fit).

```
"ConfirmDeleteThenPostBack(this, '%SomeParameter%')";
```

The function must also exist already loaded, e.g. via a ScriptLink control in the master page, or any other technique available (e.g. script tags).

One example doing exactly that could be seen here http://johanleino.wordpress.com/2009/05/12/solving-using-the-clientonclickusingpostbackevent-in-ascx-usercontrols/ and a full example to build your custom menus on SPGridView is http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powlo/archive/2007/02/25/displaying-custom-data-through-sharepoint-lists-using-spgridview-and-spmenufield.aspx

Comment: Ok. I have seen the links. But I need a javascript function for this. Can u write a function for me?